# Devise user management

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm creating a Rails app using Devise for user management (Rails 3.0.10, Devise 1.4.2).  I've got the basics going - signup, login / logout - but I can't seem to find any facility (or even documentation surrounding) user management.

In other Rails apps I've created, I've had a UsersController with an index method that allows an administrator to list all the users of a system, & to subsequently modify them through edit and update actions on the same controller.

I can't see an obvious way of doing this with Devise.  I've used the Rake tasks that come with Devise to generate editable views, which is great, but I can't figure out how to do the equivalent with the Controller.

I fear I'm missing something fundamental here.  Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devise doesn't come with any sort of Admin interface. If you are the only administrator and don't mind a little crudeness - there is always the console and/or scaffolding.

There are also a lot of good gems that make setting up admin interfaces a cinch: [Active Admin](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin), [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) and I'm sure there are a bunch more out there.